# How to bulk edit taxonomies for attachments

Tags: media-library, bulk-edit

I am looking for a way to **bulk edit** taxonomies for the attachment post type (basically, for images).

I needed to categorize a large Media Library, therefore I added a custom taxonomy by using "register_taxonomy" on the "attachments" post type.

This works fine when working "image by image", as WordPress conveniently adds a metabox on the "edit" page. But with larger quantities, I need a way to bulk edit the taxonomies.

The first approach that comes to my mind:

WordPress offers a "Bulk actions > Edit" dropdown menu for all content types (Posts, Pages, custom post types...), which allows to bulk edit taxonomies (Categories, Tags...). This would be perfect, but while this menu is present on the Media Library (on the wp-admin/upload.php page), there is no "Edit" action available.

Is there a tweak that allows this "Edit" action to become available ?

Or is there another approach to the problem? I notice that when I try to access `edit.php?post_type=attachment`, I am forwarded to `upload.php`

Comment: A quick search shows that some plugins add that functionality, for instance Divi Gallery Extended: https://diviextended.com/documentation/divi-gallery-extended/how-to-bulk-edit-images/ – but I don't need any of the Divi page builder functionality, so that would be a weird workaround.

Comment: note that this won't be possible without quickedit which isn't present on the media library page either. I do see though that you did not ask about your problem, instead you devised a solution you didn't know how to implement and ask about that instead, ( the classic X Y problem ). There are other solutions to your problem of how to bulk add attachments to categories that do not involve adding bulk edit to the media library

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for the additional info.